# Voltage of electric motor

Tags: voltage, motor, negative

What is the  range(min value and max value of average motor) of a voltage in an permanent magnet synchronous electric motor?

I am current working on a dataset of Permenant Magnet Synchronous Motor(kaggle.com/datasets/wkirgsn/electric-motor-temperature), and there the dataset consist of labels uq and dq where the value is in negative. I just want to know whether a voltage of an electric motor can be negative or not and what is the average voltage that it its range of an electric motor.

Comment: (1) Large. (2) Yes.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "dynamic range?" My initial response is that the dynamic range is infinite. But probably you and I have a different idea of what dynamic range means. In general, I think it would be helpful if you could explain a bit more. What kind of motor do you have in mind? What would it be used for? Why do you want to know the dynamic range? Maybe someone can give you a better answer if you provide that extra information.

Comment: yes sure, I am current working on a dataset of Permenant Magnet Synchronous Motor(https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wkirgsn/electric-motor-temperature), and there the dataset consist of labels uq and dq where the value is in negative....I just want to know whether a voltage of an electric motor can be negative or not and what is the average voltage that it its range of an electric motor.

Comment: please let me know if you have an idea about it

Comment: Motor voltage can be negative when the motor is spinning in reverse. uq and ud are concepts from field-oriented-control of BLDC or PMAC or PMSM motors. Motor voltages can be a few volts to thousands of volts depending on the motor type.

Comment: Looking at the dataset, it seems that the motor was nearly stationary during the time when small negative voltages existed. Once the motor was spinning Uq was high and positive. Don't focus on the data from when the motor was at 0 RPM.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the range(min value and max value of average motor) of a voltage in an permanent magnet synchronous electric motor?

Range of voltage for PMSM may start at 0V and typically ends on a value higher (or much higher) than rated voltage. It depends on how the motor is built. Higher voltage means higher stress on insulation in the motor and may destroy it.

> there the dataset consist of labels uq and dq where the value is in
> negative

These values come from field oriented control of PMSM. They are represantation of virtual voltage vector in d-q plane (see: Clarke and Park transform). These values basically are controlled to get higher speed and control power factor of the motor.

> I just want to know whether a voltage of an electric motor can be negative or not

It depends on what you ask about. Instantaneous voltage in each phase may have value below 0. That's how AC works. Voltages in d and q axes may be set below 0 to achieve some desired power factor or to set motor rotation in different direction. But to understand how it connects with three-phase AC power supply you will need to get familiar with FOC or DTC control methods.

> what is the average voltage that it its range of an electric motor

There is none. You can supply your motor with different values of voltage starting with 0 and ending with any level until you burn the windings. When you stick up to rated voltage, nothing bad should happen.